# A comparable book on Statistics Inference

Tags: statistical-inference, book-recommendation

I am using Casella and Berger for my class. But what is a comparable book on Statistic Inference? I want to understand the topic better.

Comment: "Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis"

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas!